# Visual studio trying to install to a non-existant drive with no option to change install location

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

[image]
Visual studio is trying to install to a drive letter that doesn't even exist and I have no option to change it.

[image]

plzfix kthx

Comment: Is this actually a problem? It could be that this is a virtual drive in the same style of "office to go" installations that stream data from the internet as required. Those installed used a virtual "Q:" drive if I remember correctly. Does just clicking "Install" work?

Comment: Given your second screenshot, perhaps V:\ is an unused Virtual CloneDrive? I would look at your Elaborate Bytes (Elby) control panel.

Comment: the "V:\" drive refers to a second internal SSD which I had installed for some years, but have since removed and replaced.

Comment: Visual Studio must be fully uninstalled to change this path. If it can no longer be uninstalled (because the path no longer exists), you will most likely have to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had run into this exact same issue. And the way I fixed was by following these steps.

1. Search "Manage disks and volumes" in your search bar and click on the option that comes up.
2. Choose either an unused drive, a junk drive that you are able to clear up, or create a partition in a drive that has extra space.
3. Label or re-label that drive/partition to whatever Visual Studio wants. (In your case it would be {E}.
4. Make sure to add the folders it thinks it needs to reach into the drive (for me it was called G:\VisualStudio\Components.

Now you should be able to download it again because it thinks all of the original file locations are present. And with it downloaded you should hopefully be able to manage/modify it however you want.